# Is this particle always equilibrium vertically that is $R\sin(\alpha)=mg$ where $R$ is reaction on particle

Tags: polar-coordinates, classical-mechanics

A thin smooth straight tube $OA$ is constrained to rotate with constant angular velocity $ω$ about a fixed vertical axis through $O$, and a particle is free to move in the tube. The angle between $OA$ and the upward vertical is a fixed acute angle $α$ and describe a fixed horizontal circle of radius $a$,
While the particle is in a state of steady motion the angular velocity of the tube is suddenly reduced to $\dfrac{\omega}{2}$ and is then maintained constant at the new value. Find
the time the particle takes to reach O,

My  problem is

Is this particle always equilibrium vertically that is $Rsin(\alpha)=mg$ where $R$ is reaction on particle

[image]

Edit:

$\underline{Attempt}$

I got $r$ is distance from vertical axis through $O$ which is perpendicular to the this axis then I used velocity and accelerataion  in polar coordinates

So $f=ma$ along the $r$

$$-R\cos(\alpha)=m(\ddot{r}- \frac{r{\omega^2}}{4})$$

and $f=ma$ perpendicular to the $r$

$$R\sin({\alpha})=mg$$

so then $-g\cot(\alpha)=\ddot{r}- \dfrac{r{\omega^2}}{4}$

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Analyzing the movement along the rod and defining $\delta(t)$ the distance from $O$, in the absence of friction, the dynamics are given by

$$
m\ddot\delta(t) = \frac 14m\omega^2(\delta(t)\sin\alpha)\sin\alpha-m g\cos\alpha
$$

or

$$
\ddot\delta(t) = \frac 14\omega^2\delta(t)\sin^2\alpha-g\cos\alpha
$$

Solving this ODE for $\delta(0) = \frac{g\cos\alpha}{\omega^2\sin^2\alpha},\ \ \dot\delta(0)=0$. Note that the rotation will be reduced from $\omega$ to $\omega/2$ so we have

$$
\delta(t) = \frac{g \cot (\alpha ) \csc (\alpha ) \left(4-3 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{2} \omega  t \sin (\alpha )\right)\right)}{\omega ^2}
$$

solving now $\delta(t^*)=0$ we obtain

$$
t^*=\frac{2\cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{3}\right) \csc (\alpha )}{\omega }
$$

Comment: How did you get $$ \frac 14m\omega^2(\delta(t)\sin\alpha)\sin\alpha$$?

Comment: The new rotation is $\omega_n=\omega/2$ so the horizontal force acting on the bead is $m\omega_n^2 r$ but $r = \delta\sin\alpha$ and the projection onto the rod is $m(\omega/2)^2\sin^2\alpha\delta$

Comment: Got it. Is there anything wrong in my answer ?I edited it

Comment: How did you get $m\omega^2r$ ? I think you get it since it is circular motion, if you get it I think you should add component of the $\ddot{ \delta }$

Comment: The physical movement in the rotating frame is along $\delta$ so the considered dynamics are projected onto the rod. Regarding $r$ the dynamics should read $\ddot r = \frac 14\omega^2\sin^2\alpha r - g\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$